# R: dplyr error with mutate (Column `X` must be length 1 )

Tags: r, dplyr

I've a tibble as :

```
                         gene     n
                         <chr> <int>
                         CBLB   434
 UBAC2;NA;TM9SF2;GPR18;GPR183   434
               ATP6V1G3;PTPRC   379
                     NA;BCAS1   372
```

I want to split the lines where multiple genes are separated with a ";". So :

```
                         gene     n
                         <chr> <int>
                         CBLB   434
                        UBAC2   434
                           NA   434
                       TM9SF2   434
                        GPR18   434
                       GPR183   434
                     ATP6V1G3   379
                        PTPRC   379
                           NA   372
                        BCAS1   372
```

I tried this :

```
hs %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(gene=unlist(strsplit(gene,";")),n=n)
```

But it gives me :

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `gene` must be length 1 (the group size), not 3
```

Any idea ?

here's a reproducible example :

```
structure(list(gene = c("CBLB", "UBAC2;NA;TM9SF2;GPR18;GPR183", 
"ATP6V1G3;PTPRC", "NA;BCAS1", "HINT3;NCOA7", "RALGPS2"), IS = c(434L, 
434L, 379L, 372L, 372L, 349L)), .Names = c("gene", "n"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```